# Аналог динамических коллекций в си

Tags: c, массивы, рекурсия, структуры

Есть постоянная потребность работать с разным количеством данных в Си(для примера выборка информации с бд и связывание с моделью). Для лучшего понимания использую структуры, как аналог объектов в ООП. Есть идея использовать рекурсивные структуры(односвязный список), которые будут ссылаться на следующий элемент в списке, но для примера как сортировать и удалять с середины списка для меня загадка. В си далеко не эксперт, посоветуйте решение.

Comment: удалять не штука. Сортировать - чуточку тяжелее - разделили попалам, осортировали половинки, слили вместе. Но думаю, лучше использовать просто динамический массив - тогда сортировка будет обычной библиотечной функцией

Comment: Используйте qsort http://cppstudio.com/post/891/ и не мучайтесь, он есть во всех редакциях с. Там уже все реализовано - с вас только ф-ция сравнения и массив обьектов

Comment: Если есть база - лучше использовать `order by` и не забывать что в  `order by` можно `case when ` вложить (если нужны разные сортировки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалять из середины односвязного списка достаточно просто, нужно всего лишь использовать указатель на предыдущий элемент:

```
// Удаляем элемент p
ListElem *q = listStart;  // Первый элемент списка
if (q != p) {   // Если p не первый элемент
  while (q->next != p) q = q->next;
  q->next = p->next;
}
else    // p это первый элемент
  listStart = p->next;
delete p;
```

Сортировка сложнее, но тоже не проблема:

1. Подсчитываем число элементов списка.
2. Создаем массив указателей на элементы
3. Сортируем массив указателей в соответствии со значениями элементов
4. Проходим в цикле по отсортированному массиву указателей, перезаписывая поле ссылок элементов

Пункт 4 может выглядеть так:

```
// N - число элементов
// R - массив указателей на элементы
for (i = 0; i < (N - 1); i++) R[i]->next = R[i + 1];
R[N - 1]->next = NULL;
```

Comment: как тогда добавить в середину списка?

Comment: @UjinUkr, по тому же принципу - если есть указатель p на элемент и указатель q на предыдущий элемент, то вставить элемент между ними это два присваивания: `q = elem; elem->next = p;`

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать.